# how i determine the days months and year from now to selected date subtracting [DateTime.Now-datetimepicker1]?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

i want to calculate the days month year from now date to selected date like
this is looking simple .but too complicated 
**`DateTIme.Now- datetimepicker1;`**
i want this output
**`day =456488`
`month=5554`
`year=22`**
 thanks

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate Days Months and Years as follows

```
var days = (EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays;
var months = ((EndDate.Year - StartDate.Year) * 12) + EndDate.Month - StartDate.Month;
var years = EndDate.Year - StartDate.Year;
```

Where EndDate in your case (as seen from your example) is DateTime.Now and StartDate is dateTimePicker1.Value